# Modify $mdDialog backdrop using $mdThemingProvider

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

Is it possible to define the backdrop color/shade of $mdDialog using $mdThemingProvider?

PLEASE NOTE: I know you can do this with pure CSS. The question relates to $mdThemingProvider only.

Comment: I diged out the Theming docs, and looks like the $mdThemingProvider can be used to change the entire pallet, not component specific color.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new palette extending `grey` palette specifying a value for `900` shade.

```
    angular.module('moduleName').config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
      var redTheme = $mdThemingProvider.theme('redTheme', 'default');
      var redPalette = $mdThemingProvider.extendPalette('grey', {
        '900': '#f00'
      });
      $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('redPalette', redPalette);
      redTheme.backgroundPalette('redPalette');
    });
```

example:

```js
angular.module('BackdropApp', ['ngAria', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMaterial'], function($mdThemingProvider) {
     var redTheme = $mdThemingProvider.theme('redTheme', 'default');
    var redPalette = $mdThemingProvider.extendPalette('grey', {
     '900': '#f00'
    });
    $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('redPalette', redPalette);
    redTheme.backgroundPalette('redPalette');
    })

    .run(function($rootScope, $mdDialog) {
     $rootScope.showAlert = function() {
      $mdDialog.show($mdDialog.alert({
       content: 'A red backdrop',
       ok: 'OK'
      }));
     };
    });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.css">
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="BackdropApp" md-theme="redTheme">
   <md-toolbar> </md-toolbar>
  <md-button ng-click="showAlert()" class="md-raised md-primary">Show Alert</md-button>
</body>
</html>
```